# What Texture Map is This?

Tags: texturing

I downloaded an fbx which came with a diffuse and normal map along with a third map which I really don't know what it is.[image: What is this?] Also, how would I hook this up to a Principled BSDF?

Comment: Most likely it is an image composed of 3 black and white images which were put into 3 color channels of this image, one into R, another into blue etc. One can only guess what exactly those initial images were for, it depends on project quite a bit. It could be roughness + metallic + ambient occlusion, but not necessarily

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess I'll have to try a few things.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the texture is, but the color needs to go to Metallic, Specular, and Anistropic with the alpha in the roughness.